# AWS load balancer security group not allowing traffic even when all allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer, aws-security-group

[image]

The security group assigned to it has both Inbound and Outbound rule as ALL traffic and ALL port range, so why does it say it's not allowing traffic on that listener port?

[image]

Comment: Does the balancer actually work?

Comment: I added Route 53 that alias it and point the namecheap nameservers to Route 53, the website gives Bad gateway error.

Comment: So it sounds like the load balancer itself is working, otherwise it wouldn't be able to return that error.  Are the instance targets showing healthy?

Comment: Ok resolved. The target group must use HTTP instead of HTTPS https://i.imgur.com/OOZBZHp.png, presumably because my Express server is listening on HTTP. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the LoadBalancer was created by ElasticBeanstalk environment, you would have to add the listener in the ElasticBeanstalk configurations

Comment: Once you added the listener, make sure you click on the "Save" button at the very bottom of the page. It can easily be missed